# Extending the Value of non-Missing Cells to Subsequent Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, shift

This is what I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[6,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]})
   A    B
0  1  6.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  NaN
3  4  3.0
4  5  NaN
```

I would like to extend non-missing values of B to missing values of B underneath, so I have:

```
   A    B    C 
0  1  6.0  6.0
1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
3  4  3.0  3.0
4  5  NaN  NaN
```

I tried something like this, and it worked last night:

```
for i in df.index:
    df['C'][i]=np.where(pd.isnull(df['B'].iloc[i]),df['C'][i-1],df.B.iloc[i])
```

But when I woke up this morning it said it didn't recognize 'C.' I couldn't identify the conditions in which it worked and didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you were using a notebook environment where C was already a column in the dataframe. But when you restarted the Kernel, `C` was no longer in the dataframe. You can't call `C` in `np.where` if `C` doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks bro. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas `fillna()` method to forward fill the missing values with the last non-null value. See the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for more details.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [6, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan]
})

df['C'] = df['B'].fillna(method='ffill')

df

#    A    B    C
# 0  1  6.0  6.0
# 1  2  NaN  6.0
# 2  3  NaN  6.0
# 3  4  3.0  3.0
# 4  5  NaN  3.0
```